# What to do with a leaking ceiling

Tags: ceiling, leak

I live in New York with 45 degree temperatures, and after heavy rain last night I have leaking ceilings all over my house.  Water is just seeping through the ceiling, drops and stops.  The water dries up in less than 3 minutes, with no sign of water marks.  It's happening even 10 hours after the rain stopped.

What can I do to correct it?

Comment: What's above the ceiling?  Roof, another floor, bathroom, etc?  If it's a roof, what kind, and when was it last replaced?  Have you looked at the underside of the roof (attic) for signs of leaking?

Answer (score 3):

Resist the temptation to see it as a ceiling problem that can be patched from inside. Doing so will only provide temporary relief, if at all. To fix the root of the problem, you probably need to inspect and fix the roof, i.e. from the outside.